# Cannot not connect to SQL Server with a user account that I created: Error 233

Tags: authentication, tcp, named-pipes, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2017

I've pasted the specific technical details of the error below. I'm running SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Virtual Machine.

I know that this question has been asked many times and i have tried all of the suggested fixes that were posted but still no luck. So let me detail what exactly I have done so far:

- On SQL Server Management Studio, I have enabled SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode for the server authentication settings
- Again, in SSMS in server propeties > connections I have made sure that the maximum number of concurrent connections is 0=unlimited
- In SQL Server Configuration Manager, I have now enabled Named Pipes and TCP/IP. The client protocol order is as follows: 1.Shared Memory, 2.TCP/IP and 3.Named Pipes.
- After all thos changes I did a hail mary and ran this query that I found from another forum. It's supposed to ensure that more than one person is able to log on to SQL server (it still failed)

> sp_configure ‘show advanced options’, 1;
>
> go
>
> reconfigure
>
> go
>
> sp_configure ‘user connections’, 0
>
> go
>
> reconfigure
>
> go

---

**Here is the specific error I get when I try top log in with the user account that I created:**

> Cannot connect to A98SV201BDD2T.
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
>   (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=233&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Server Name: A98SV201BDD2T Error Number: 233 Severity: 20 State: 0
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo
>   ci, IServerType server)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
>
> ===================================
>
> No process is on the other end of the pipe

**Interestingly, when I try to log in again immediately after the first failed attempt I get a slightly different error message:**

> Login failed for user 'PhocasAdmin'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Server Name: A98SV201BDD2T Error Number: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 1 Line Number: 65536
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo
>   ci, IServerType server)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

Any ideas on what coud be causing this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the firewall settings? Is that a named SQL instance or the default one? Is the SQL browser service running?